# Rails live reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, livereload, esbuild

I am trying to configure a live reload using `Rails 7.1.3`, `esbuild` and `.scss` files.

This is my `esbuild.config.js` file:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const isProduction = process.env.RAILS_ENV === 'production';
const watchMode = process.argv.includes('--watch') || process.argv.includes('--reload');
const reloadMode = process.argv.includes('--reload');
const port = 3030;

const esbuildConfig = {
  entryPoints: [path.join('app/javascript', 'application.js')],
  bundle: true,
  minify: isProduction,
  sourcemap: !isProduction,
  target: 'es2015',
  outdir: path.join('app/assets/builds'),
};

esbuild.build(esbuildConfig).then(() => {}).catch(() => process.exit(1));

let clients = [];
let clientId = 0;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  });

  const thisClientId = clientId++;
  clients[thisClientId] = res;

  req.on('close', () => {
    delete clients[thisClientId];
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

chokidar.watch([
  'app/javascript/**/*',
  'app/views/**/*',
  'app/assets/stylesheets/**/*',
]).on('all', () => {
  esbuild.build(esbuildConfig).then(() => {
    clients.forEach((res) => {
      res.write('data: update\n\n');
    });
  }).catch(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

And this is part of my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.config.js",
    "build:css:compile": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "build:css:prefix": "postcss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --use=autoprefixer --output=./app/assets/builds/application.css",
    "build:css": "yarn build:css:compile && yarn build:css:prefix",
    "watch:css": "nodemon --watch ./app/assets/stylesheets/ --ext scss --exec \"yarn build:css\""
  },
```

I have a `live_reload.js` file:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3030');

  eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data === 'update') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };
}
```

And everything work fine, but the main problem is that when I do a change in a `.scss` file it takes times to build the `.css` and before it finish the process my page already reloaded.

And this is my `Procfile.dev` file:

```
css: yarn watch:css
web: env RUBY_DEBUG_OPEN=true bin/rails server
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
js: yarn build --watch
```

I tried using `LiveReload` plugin but it doesn't reloead the page.

And also running my app using `overmind` but still having the same behavior that reload the page before the `.css` process is over.

And I don't wnat to use `webpacker` because has been retired.

What can I do to solve that?